# Where is $-2R_{ij}\nabla_jf$ from?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

> [image]
>
> [image]

$M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold,$g_{ij}$ and $f(t)$ is defined as first picture.

I want to compute (as equality with red line in second picture)
$$
\int_M-\nabla_if\nabla_i(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}dV  \\
=\int_M-\nabla_if(2\nabla_j(\nabla_i\nabla_jf)-2R_{ij}\nabla_jf-2\langle \nabla f
,\nabla_i\nabla f\rangle)e^{-f}dV
$$

I try that:
$$
\nabla_i(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)=
(2\nabla_i(g^{kl}\nabla_k\nabla_lf)-\nabla_i\langle \nabla f,\nabla f\rangle)
$$
I assume that, although $g_{ij}(t)$ evolve with $t$, but when $t$ is given, I can choose a normal coordinate such that $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$. Then $\nabla_kg_{ij}=0,\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$. Then:
$$
\nabla_i(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)=
(2\nabla_i(g^{kl}\nabla_k\nabla_lf)-\nabla_i\langle \nabla f,\nabla f\rangle)\\
=2\nabla_i(\nabla_j(\nabla_jf))-2\langle \nabla_i\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle   \\
=2\nabla_j(\nabla_i(\nabla_jf))-2\langle \nabla_i\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle  
$$
But there is not $-2R_{ij}\nabla_jf$.

The above picture is from 201th page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

Comment: Whenever you want to switch $\nabla_i$ and $\nabla_j$, you always come  up with a Ricci term.

Comment: @JohnMa Clever, why I can't think it .

Comment: @JohnMa  There still be some thing wrong. Because this is integrate, normal coordinate is useless. so, there will be a term with $\nabla_i g^{kl}$, is right ?

Comment: There will not be a term $\nabla_i g^{kl}$ since this term will always be zero (that's the metric condition).